# FAILCould not initialize class org.sikuli.script.Screen' sikuli C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, sikuli

I am using sikuli in c#. I have installed java in my pc and wrote the simple code to test which will be go to google.com and search a text. 
My code is

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ChromeDriverService service1 = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
        service1.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;

        var options1 = new ChromeOptions();
        options1.AddArguments("--disable-notifications");
        options1.AddArgument("--start-maximized");

        var driver = new ChromeDriver(service1, options1);

        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://google.com");
        driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

        APILauncher launch = new APILauncher(true);
        string path = "E:/Test/";

        launch.Start();


        Sikuli4Net.sikuli_REST.Screen screen = new Sikuli4Net.sikuli_REST.Screen();


        //Write Name
        Pattern write = new Pattern(path + "write.PNG");

        screen.Wait(write, 500);
        screen.Type(write, "Tom Cruise", KeyModifier.NONE);

        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        //Click On search Button
        Pattern search = new Pattern(path + "click.PNG");
        screen.Wait(search, 500);
        screen.Click(search, true);

        launch.Stop();

    }
```

And I am getting this error

[image: Error Sikuli]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having a similar error (not related with C#, however it can be useful for someone else). I migrated last week to Java 11, and started to get the same error as you `could not initialize class org.sikuli.script.screen` (I was using Intellij IDE), so I needed to downgrade to JDK 8 - currenty version is jdk1.8.0_202), and now it´s working the same way again. Maybe it can be some start point for you take a look.